# Rock Paper Scissors.

Tags: probability

I came across a question yesterday, the question states, there are some kids in a playground. They decide to play a game of Rock paper scissors. We are given R rocks, S scissors, and P papers. each kid can choose either to be a rock, paper or scissor. Rock beats Scissor, Scissor beats Paper and Paper beats Rock. We have to find what is the probability for Rock, Scissor and Paper(for each of them) to be the lone survivor in the game.
Now they gave some examples

> 1. R=2,S=2,P=2 -> P(Rock)=0.3333 P(Scissor) =0.3333 P(Paper)=0.3333
> 2. R=2,S=1,P=2 -> P(Rock)=0.1500 P(Scissor) =0.3000 P(Paper)=0.5500
> 3. R=1,S=1,P=3 -> P(Rock)=0.057(approx) P(Scissor) =0.65(approx) P(Paper)=0.28(approx)

I don't want any solution. I just want to understand the problem. I did some permutations, wrote a brute force code, but all failed. Can anyone help me to understand the problem, with an explanation for the test cases?
[here](https://ideone.com/7IAql3) is my bruteforce code.

Comment: This is a poorly explained problem. Can you share the exact original text of the problem, in case there are some details you missed? Based only on your explanation, my best guess is that the items (rocks, papers, and scissors) are being randomly paired against each other and the loser eliminated until only one is left.

Comment: Can you show your brute force code? (to see how you (wrongly) understood the problem, which makes it easier for others to avoid the path)

Comment: @Rahul yes, this is really a poorly explained problem. It was asked in a coding contest. The page has been removed by the admin. But I assure you, only this much information was there.

Comment: @user202729 https://ideone.com/7IAql3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand the question in the following way:

> There are $R$ rocks, $S$ scissors and $P$ papers, objects for each match will be taken independently and uniformly, after the match the looser is eliminated. What are the probabilities of each of them to eventually become the sole survivor?

Suppose $p$ is the function, that maps triples $(R, S, P)$ to the respective probabilities $(p_R, p_S, p_P)$.

Then $p$ satisfies the following recurrence relation:

$$p(R, S, P) = \begin{cases} (0, 0, 0) & \quad R=S=P=0 \\ (1, 0, 0) & \quad P = 0,R > 0 \\ (0, 1, 0) & \quad R = 0, S >0 \\ (0, 0, 1) & \quad S = 0, P>0 \\ \frac{2(PRp(R-1, S, P) + RSp(R, S-1, P) + SPp(R, S, P-1))}{(R + S + P)^2 - (R^2 + S^2 + P^2)} & \quad RSP>0 \end{cases}$$

That recurrence comes from the equality $$2PRp(R-1, S, P) + 2RSp(R, S-1, P) + 2SPp(R, S, P-1) + (R^2 + S^2 + P^2)p(R, S, P) = (R + S + P)^2p(R, S, P)$$ which you get when you list all possible outcomes from the first match.

This recurrent formula allows you to calculate the probabilities for all $(R, S, P) \in \mathbb{N}^3$.

Also note, that everywhere above addition and multiplication by constants of triples was elementwise.

Comment: I think you have some unwanted $T$'s and $t$ in the displayed equation explaining the recurrence. Also, note, the denominator in the $RSP\gt0$ case simplifies to $2(PR+RS+SP)$, which makes the expression easier to read as $${PR\over PR+RS+SP}p(R-1,S,P)+{RS\over PR+RS+SP}p(R,S-1,P)+{SP\over PR+RS+SP}p(R,S,P-1)$$